# Connectiong To Oracle Via KeepTool

Tags: database, linux, oracle

I'm new to KeepTool and Oracle And I'm going to connect to my Oracle database on a remote server (Linux) from KeepTool in my Windows 7. It asks me to enter the Host:Port:SID to connect but it didn't work when I use the Linux server IP address or HostName specified in tnsNames.ora. Should I add the IP Address to tnsnames.ora?
Would you please help me?

Regards

```
RS = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = **linux-y29w.site**)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = RS)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check from your machine
1) If your Linux server is reachable (PING it)
2) If your Linux server is listening on port 1521 (You can use **papping** utility)

If both of above seems ok. Please **write Exact Error** you receiving.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes. The server is reachable and linux-y29.site is listening to the port but when I try to connect to the server, it returns ora-12170: TNS Connection Timeout occured :(

Comment: open CMD and type **TNSPING [servers IP Address]**  if it can ping your TNS successfully there is some problem in keeptool otherwise check connectivity issue.